# Update Cordova Project Android Platform

Tags: cordova

I am using Cordova and I need android version 6.3.0 as required by a plugin that I want to use.

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" at "4.0.3" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.1.2, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0
```

My problem is how can I update my android version, I try to use this code

```
cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```

Still the version is 6.1.2 when I try to build

[image]

Comment: Did you remove the old android platform ?

Comment: No, I never execute a command like that

Comment: try `cordova platform remove android` before you add the new one. I'm not 100% sure just adding a new platform will replace the old one. I always remove it like this. On a side note - what is that graphical interface you have in that screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest cli you can use in Phonegap Build is 7.1.0, you can set it with:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
```

That will use cordova-android 6.3.0 as platform, so the plugin should install fine.